# Law of large numbers: other formulae

Tags: law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots $ be an infinite sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $E(X_i)=\mu$ and $\mbox{Var}(X_i) < \infty$.

The law of large numbers states $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{X_i}{n} = \mu$.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) mentions that "other formulas that look similar are not verified".

In other words $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i = n\mu$ is not correct?

Is there a counter-example or an obvious reason why this is not the case?

Comment: Note also that the Law of Large Numbers does not require the existence of the variance of the $X_i$'s.

Comment: A warning that arises every time in the classroom:$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i = n\mu$$does not make sense (mathematically) since the lhs does not depend on $n$ as a limit, while the rhs does.

Comment: Thank you @Xi'an. So if $E(X_i)=\mu/n$ where $i=1,2,...n$ then I assume $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i =\mu$ would make sense?

Comment: No it does not make sense either: $\mathbb E(X_i)=\mu/n$ has the lhs depending on $i$ and the rhs depending on $n$.

Comment: Thanks again @Xi'an. I think I understand it better now. It also cannot be true, because with $E(X_i)= \mu/n$ and $\mbox{Var}(X_i)>0$, we have $E (\sum_{i=1}^n X_i) = \mu$, but  $\mbox{Var}(\sum_{i=1}^n  X_i)$ does not approach zero, as $n$ increases.

Comment: Sorry, but the fundamental reason is that $\mathbb E(X_i)=\mu/n$ does not make sense mathematically. The random variable $X_i$ for one given $i\in\mathbb N^*$, does not depend on $n$.

Comment: Thanks again @Xi'an, your comments helped a lot.   I am modelling an actual situation with sets containing different numbers of random variables, where the expected value of the random variables in a particular set is $\mu/n$ with $n$ the cardinal number of the set.  I was attempting to link this model to the law of large numbers, but this is obviously not possible.

Comment: In that case, you need to rephrase the question differently. It sounds like you are dealing with [the law of large numbers for triangular arrays](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1317869/14893).

Answer (score 2):

What do LLNs say?

At the risk of getting too oversimplistic, for independent sequence $\langle X_i\rangle_{i\in\mathbb  N},$ they say the partial sum (or average, precisely)

$$\frac{1}{n}(X_1+X_2+\ldots+ X_n) \tag 1$$

converges to common mean $\mu$ in certain sense provided second moment or forth moment be finite and uniformly bounded depending on what convergence one is bothered with.

When $\rm i.i.d.$ is imposed, only the first moment needs to be finite.

What is Wikipedia saying?

It is only saying form like

$$\sum_{i=1}^n X_i -n\times \bar X$$

doesn't make sense for

> not only does it not converge toward zero as $n$ increases, but it tends to increase in absolute value as $n$ increases.

Finally as Xi'an noted in the [comments](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/592128/law-of-large-numbers-other-formulae#comment1095591_592128), be careful with indexing set and limiting variable.

---

### Further Read:

$\rm [I]$ A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory, *Jeffrey S. Rosenthal,* World Scientific Publishing, $2006, $ section $5.3,~5.4,$ pp. $60-64.$